# SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL not working Django 2.0.6

Tags: python, django, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am working in a web app for my organization (lets say 'students.uni' and 'academics.uni')
My organization uses Google services so those are google domains and I want to limit the acces to the app only for those domains using 'social_django'
I am working with Django 2.0.6 and Python 3.6.5

I am using this to limit the acces to the app, works good:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = ['student.uni', 'academics.uni']
```

Works good when I do log-in or register with an allowed account, but, when the domain of the account is not allowed I want to redirect or send the user to another page to let him know what happened.

I have been trying with:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = 'principal'
```

But I can't get it to work since I keep getting either a AuthForbidden exception or a 500 error if I set `DEBUG = False`

Any suggestion on how should I proceed in order to redirect or send a message when the domain is not allowed? Many thanks

Some code:

Settings.py (not all, but relevant code)

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.user',
    'apps.inv',
    'apps.sol',
    'social_django',
]



AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',  # for Google authentication
 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',  # for Google authentication
 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',  # for Google authentication

 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

LOGIN_URL =  'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'principal'
#DEBUG = False
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = 'principal'

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY ='****.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = '******'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = ['student.uni', 'academics.uni']
```

page thatI get when try to login with another domain account:

```
AuthForbidden at /auth/complete/google-oauth2/
Your credentials aren't allowed
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/complete/google-oauth2/?state=8*********&code=4/***********-***********************************&authuser=0&session_state=*****************************..e40c&prompt=none
Django Version: 2.0.6
Exception Type: AuthForbidden
Exception Value:    
Your credentials aren't allowed
Exception Location: C:\ambientes\prueba\lib\site-packages\social_core\pipeline\social_auth.py in auth_allowed, line 14
Python Executable:  C:\ambientes\prueba\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\proyectosDjango\\Modular',
 'C:\\ambientes\\prueba\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\espar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\espar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\espar\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\ambientes\\prueba',
 'C:\\ambientes\\prueba\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Dom, 1 Jul 2018 15:45:32 -0500
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a (lot of?) research I found a way to do it.
Resuming: I want only emails from a list of domains (google provided) to be able to register on my site: example1@domain1.com, example2@another.domain.com
you can find the basic steps to login with google [here](https://fosstack.com/how-to-add-google-authentication-in-django/) and [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html)
After doing those steps, you'll be able to login with any google, facebook, twitter account, regardless of it's domain.
Next step is to define the next variable in your **settings.py**

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_WHITELISTED_DOMAINS = ['domain1.edu.com', 'domain2.edu.com']
```

This will filter the domains that you want to be able to register.

you could also set up the next ones, though these are irrelevant to me right now I think is better to have them

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/user/error/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = False
```

Error url defines which path should the app redirect to if an error happens when logging-in

**My solution starts here:**
when the sistem detects that your domain **is** allowed everything should go good, but when it detects that your domain is not in the whitelist, it throws an **AuthForbidden** exception (yes, even when I defined that it shouldn't raise exceptions with the variable above). Since the exception is not an error, it will not go to SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR_URL and you will get the exception screen.

The solution is create a custom pipeline method. You can find an introduction to pipelines [here](http://rahmonov.me/posts/introduction-to-python-social-auth/)

1- Create a **pipeline.py** file in the same folder as **settings.py**
2- Define the method auth_allowed so it doesn't raise an exception but redirect to somewhere else (or do whatever you want). I did it this way:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def auth_allowed(backend, details, response, *args, **kwargs):
    if not backend.auth_allowed(response, details):
        return redirect('user:error')#<-here goes your url as defined on your urls.py
```

3- Define the pipeline in **settings.py** replacing the auth_allowed with your custom method

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'modular.pipeline.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

(modular is the name of my proyect, write the name of your proyect)
(many posts will show you the methods called only by 'social.pipeline...' I used 'social_core.pipeline...' instead because social gave me an error)

this should work. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thank you so much - it was very difficult to find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Thanks, this was really useful!